# Remove WordPress' license.txt using plugin

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to write a plugin to return `HTTP 404` when user request   `license.txt`, what is the correct `action` to hook (both efficient and effective way to block)?

**Update:**

Because I don't have control to the web server, I must do this as a plugin

Comment: Cluttering the hook ecosphere with something like this sounds like overkill. Is just deleting the file not a better option? Or writing an automated task that deletes it?

Comment: Becoz I don't have control to the web server, I must do this as a plugin

Comment: Isn't preventing anyone viewing the license against the license terms

Answer (score 8):

Solution is actually pretty straightforward.
You need to create plugin which writes to .htaccess.

1. In the /wp-content/plugins create **licence_redirect** folder.
2. In that folder create **licence_redirect.php** file.
3. Paste code below to this **licence_redirect.php** php file:

> ```
> <?php
> /*
> Plugin Name: Licence redirect
> Description: Redirects license.txt. to 404
> Author: J. Wrong
> Version: 0.1
> */
> ?>
> <?php
> function lr_flush_rewrites() {
>     global $wp_rewrite;
>     $wp_rewrite->flush_rules();
> }
>
> function lr_add_rewrites() {
>     global $wp_rewrite;
>     $lr_wp_rules = array(
>         'license\.txt$' => '[R=404,L]',
>     );
>
>     $wp_rewrite->non_wp_rules = $lr_wp_rules + $wp_rewrite->non_wp_rules;
> }
>
> register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'lr_flush_rewrites' );
> add_action('generate_rewrite_rules', 'lr_add_rewrites');
> ```

1. Install and activate plugin.
2. In admin panel go to Setting -> Permalinks
3. Press save changes
   From now on your license.txt requests will be redirected to 404.
   If you can't create folders on server then you'll need to zip the plugin's folder and upload it using WP admin.
   Cheers... counting bounty now :P

Answer (score 2):

You can't. With a standard WordPress `.htaccess`, requests to static files are not passed to PHP at all, so there is no way to hook them.

Comment: Unless your .htaccess tells Apache to redirect a request to PHP anyway. Wordpress already rewrites its .htaccess based on permalink settings, there might be a way to add your own rules at that time.

Comment: That's true. If you could modify the `.htaccess`, though, you could just do that and not bother with a plugin!

Answer (score 1):

There is a plug-in that will do this for you.  Just set the file you want to redirect and its target. It even keeps a log

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/redirection/